# How to send a push notification in unificationengine

Tags: unificationengine

How to send a push notification to a channel in unificationengine?

If a user is already created the channel via UE.

Answer (score 0):

Example for pushing messages to UE

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/push/notification -u CONNECTOR_KEY:CONNECTOR_SECRET –data “{ \"channel\”: \“6d2d2111-d3b6-4ac9-8e67-55980a141fdd_sms\”, \“data\”: \“test message\”}“ -k

The documentation for push messages is given in Connector section in https://developer.unificationengine.com.